# bcrypt cost 10/12/14 brute force time?

Tags: brute-force, bcrypt

Earlier I added bcrypt with cost 12 (15 is a bit too long for login, 12 looks about right).

I'm also planning to add the https://howsecureismypassword.net/ open source version but I'd rather not scare people signing up.

The default example has "calculationsPerSecond: 10 billion" -- is there any information on how many password attempts could be done against bcrypt with cost 10-14 on Today's hardware?

The most recent information I found is an Ars Technica 2012 article describing seemingly 71k/sec with better than average hardware: [25-GPU cluster cracks every standard Windows password in <6 hours](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/) -- it doesn't mention the cost used though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### From 2014, hardware included

I've found [a paper](https://www.usenix.org/conference/woot14/speaker-or-organizer/katja-malvoni-university-zagreb) which looks like it contains the facts you need.

There is a table which shows the performance of certain devices corresponding to the cost factor:

```
Cost / Device   12        10        8         5
Epiphany 16     9.64 c/s  38.7 c/s  151.3 c/s 1207 c/s
Zynq-7020       64.83 c/s 253.1 c/s 932.6 c/s 4571 c/s
Zynq-7045       226.3 c/s 888.6 c/s 3371 c/s  20538 c/s
HD 7970         35.76 c/s 142.9 c/s 569.2 c/s 4556 c/s
FX-8120         42.93 c/s 171.2 c/s 680.2 c/s 5275 c/s
Xeon Phi 5110P  50.18 c/s 200.7 c/s 800.8 c/s 6285 c/s
i7-4770K        53.67 c/s 214.2 c/s 852.8 c/s 6615 c/s
```

It is worth noting that three devices, Epiphany 16, Zynq-7020 and Zynq-7045 are low-power parallel platforms. You can read more about this in the paper I linked at heading numbers 3, 3.1 and 3.2

### From June 2016, hardware not mentioned.

[This website](https://pthree.org/2016/06/28/lets-talk-password-hashing/) shows the times to hash a password with bcrypt (and some other hashing functions) depending on the cost.

[This image](https://pthree.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/bcrypt.png) from the website shows the timings for bcrypt with cost values ranging from 6 - 20.

#### Hashes per second

- Cost of **10**: **14.7** hashes per  second
- Cost of **11**: **7.3** hashes per second
- Cost of **12**: **4.4** hashes per second
- Cost of **13**: **1.9** hashes per second
- Cost of **14**: **0.9** hashes per second

Comment: That's just his own machine though? From what I can see it doesn't mention specs...could be an old P4

Comment: I've edited my answer to include another source which has hardware specifications included.

Comment: Thanks :o c/s = attempts per second? I'll assume 100m calcs/sec is way too high then in the present day

Comment: What is **c/s**?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [table](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40) can help? It gives hashrates on 8 NVidia GTX 1080 GPUs.

The comments mention the following:

> sroussey commented on 21 Oct 2016 I understand the desire to keep
>   bcrypt at work factor 5, but can you do additional tests with a factor
>   of 10 and 15. Best to start the 15 now and have a history of how it
>   progresses. And 10 is common today. Thanks!
>
> epixoip commented on 6 Dec 2016 @sroussey the work factor is log2, so
>   you can simply divide the hashrate in half any number of times to get
>   the hash rate for higher work factors. For example, 105700 H/s for
>   cost 5... 105700 / 2^(10-5) =~ 3303 H/s for cost=10, 105700 / 2^(15-5)
>   =~ 103 H/s for cost=15. No further benchmarking necessary ;) But the reason why we benchmark with static parameters like this is so we can
>   easily compare device performance spanning several hardware
>   generations.

So it seems that you can calculate the hashrate on 8 GTX 1080 GPUs for all parameters of bcrypt. For cost 12 it would be 105700 / 2ˆ(12-5) = 825 hashes per second. For 1 GPU you could divide this by 8 (rough estimate).